# How to get response and use in other steps in pytest-bdd as argument

Tags: python, api, pytest-bdd

I tried to make a design for my API Python Project with pytest-bdd. I made "common, features, test" folders.

And in the feature file, I added my post, delete , get, put cases. I  also seperated post.feature delete.feature etc.. due to there are lost of cases.

And then  I generated my post_steps.py from the feature files. And There are some common steps in all steps pages. and so I decided to put them to commonsteps.py under the common folder.

Then,in the common.py, There some common methods as in the below asserts status code:

```
  @then('Status code of response should be 200')
    def status_code_of_response_should_be_200():
        assert status_code == 200
```

My tests starts with mypost.py and then starts to use this common methods but How can I pass response,status code to this page ? because I need to verify .
In a nutshell, How Can I get response as a parameter from different steps page?enter image description here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you actually try to achieve...
I assume you want to know how to pass the response object you receive in step `When Execute PostAPI method with valid data` to the step `Then Status code of response should be 200`.

There are multiple solutions, that use the same concept:

1. Create a "context" fixture and use it as parameter in step `When Execute PostAPI method with valid data` and `Then Status code of response should be 200` and store the received response in there.
2. Create a fixture for the HTTP client you use in `When Execute PostAPI method with valid data` and pass that as parameter in step `Then Status code of response should be 200`. Then you can access the HTTP client there and presumably the response as well.

Examples:

## Use a context object

```py
@pytest.fixture
def step_context():
    return {'response': None}

@when("Execute PostAPI method with valid data")
def do_post(step_context):
    # Do HTTP request and retrieve response here ...
    step_context['response'] = response

@then("Status code of response should be 200")
def assert_status(step_context):
    assert step_context['response'].status_code == 200
```

## HTTP client as fixture

```py
@pytest.fixture
def http_client():
    return HTTPClient()

@when("Execute PostAPI method with valid data")
def do_post(http_client):
    # Do HTTP request and retrieve response here ...
    
@then("Status code of response should be 200")
def assert_status(http_client):
    assert http_client.status_code == 200
```